# gridview cannot display chinese that retrieve straight away from database

Tags: asp.net, gridview, eval

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #middle{
            float:none;
        }
        #left{
            float:left;
        }

        #right{
            float:right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div style="font-family:Arial">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"
                    Text='<%# Eval("USERID").ToString() +"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+ Eval("USERNAME").ToString() +"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+ Eval("USERPOSITION").ToString()%>' runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</div>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SOConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SOConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT USERID, USERNAME, USERPOSITION FROM USERMASTER"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my code and when Eval() retrieve the USERID from database, it couldn't show mandarin. All the character became ???.
anyone can help me on this?
On previous if I use C# then it will show mandarin wihtout any coding behind. maybe it is asp.net. anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that a character encoding is specified. See [Specifying the document's character encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#charset) on how this can be done.

Make sure that the character encoding is the same for the document and the result of the `Eval` statement.

Comment: do you mind guide me how to do it? I nvr do any encoding in asp.net.

Comment: You can use attributes of `Page Directive` as `RequestEncoding="utf-8" ResponseEncoding="utf-8"` [Link about this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39d1w2xf%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

Comment: @शेखर I added but still not working,..
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SOConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=MSDAORA.1;Data Source=XE;Password=1234;User ID=so"
      providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <globalization
      fileEncoding="utf-8"
      requestEncoding="utf-8"
      responseEncoding="utf-8"
      culture="en-US"
      uiCulture="de-DE"
    />
  </system.web>
</configuration>